# Ball rolling on slopes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

In this case, when the ball rolls to the lowest position, how will be the normal force by slope B act on the ball (assume the angle of inclination of slope A is $30^\circ$)?

**Attempts:**

This is originally a homework question, and I just use conservation of energy to find $v$ : $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + m(1)(g) = m(g)(2\cos(45^\circ))
$
However I think the ball will encounter a normal force when it reaches slope B, which it would lose some energy. I think if the angle between two slopes is $ 90 ^\circ$ then the ball can't move up to slope B. I tried taking components of the Normal force:$　N\cos(15^\circ) = mg\sin(30^\circ
)$
However I don't understand how will the $N\sin(15^\circ)$ act on the ball when it moves up along slope B? Should I take component of $N\sin(15^\circ)$?

Comment: Normal force won't be dissipative ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [velocity of an object after leaving a ramp](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297922/velocity-of-an-object-after-leaving-a-ramp)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask the actual question. I guess(from your energy equation) the question is: 'What is the minimum speed with which the ball must be released so that it reaches point B?' Even then the solution wouldn't be simple. There will be collision of the ball with the inclined plane and the coefficient of restitution is not given. But if you assume that the collision is perfectly elastic, the ball won't reach point B. If you assume that the collision is perfectly inelastic,

The loss in kinetic energy of the ball appears as heat.

And the work done by normal reaction (in this case) is the kinetic energy lost or the heat energy generated. To calculate work done by a force, you always don't have to evaluate the integral of dot product of force and displacement.